# margin left on text overfow css

Tags: html, css, responsive

Is there an option in CSS to add a **left padding** to the contents **overflowing** on responsive devices ?

input

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit donec euismod ipsum et nisl faucibus
```

**Desired Output** on text reflow in *responsive displays* without word wrap

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
   donec euismod ipsum et nisl faucibus
```

Note the padding in the left to fit responsive screens. That essentially might convey that the line has to be percieved as a first line, though broken to fit screen.

My use case deals with accommodating lines of text in a single line (in larger devices this wont prove a problem.); whereas in handheld displays it has to be broken down obviously. 
Please do note that we are aware of word wrap to fit screen, but it affects the aesthetics of display and prolonged horizontal scrolling is undesirable as we have considerable large number of those instances in page. I am using jekyll with markdown.

> TL;DR

Would require CSS to alter the overflown text only without needing to scroll horizontally.
(i.e) 
*Would like to add a text indent : 1em to overflowing text*

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
style="white-space:normal;word-wrap:break-word;"
```

**white-space** = Break the sentence with spacing to the next line.

**word-wrap** = Break the continuous sentence/word to the next line.

Comment: This doesn't do the work though [https://jsfiddle.net/tuvedyjs/ ]

Comment: Would like to add an _text indent : 1em_ to overflowing text